# Buttons and other active parts of TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button

I have a problem with TKinter radiobuttons, checkerboxes, buttons and fields. I'm not sure if I can put multiple questions in one but basically it's a single question but quite big. First part is that I can't setup my checkerboxes correctly. I wrote a gray bg and almost white fg but on Mac it shows everything in white. I'll attach a few screenshots but I think I described my problem really well. Here is a part of the code with a problem:

```
buttonVR = tk.Button(window, bg="gray15", text=f"{modes[0]}", font=("Arial", 10), activebackground="black", fg="lemon chiffon", command=VR, width=24, height=3)
```

```
import tkinter.messagebox as tmb
import tkinter.filedialog as tfd
from tkinter.ttk import Radiobutton
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Checkbutton  
import tkinter as tk
import re
import math

global window

def MainWindow():
    def HelpMain():
        tmb.showinfo(f"Help", "blah-blah-blah, demo v")
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title(f"{app_name} {version} by {company}")
    window.geometry("500x240")
    window.configure(bg="gray22", border= "10")
    window.resizable(False, False)

    buttonVR = tk.Button(window, bg="gray15", text=f"{modes[0]}", font=(
        "Arial", 10,), activebackground="black", fg="lemon chiffon", command=VR, width=24, height=3)
    buttonVR.grid(column=0, row=0, pady=5)

    buttonPR = tk.Button(window, bg="gray15", text=f"{modes[1]}", font=(
        "Arial", 10), activebackground="black", fg="lemon chiffon", command=PR, width=24, height=3)
    buttonPR.grid(column=0, row=1, pady=10)

    buttonAR = tk.Button(window, bg="gray15", text=f"{modes[2]}", font=(
        "Arial", 10), activebackground="black", fg="lemon chiffon", command=AR, width=24, height=3)
    buttonAR.grid(column=0, row=2, pady=5)

    buttonHelp = tk.Button(window, bg="gray15", text="Help", font=(
        "Arial", 10), activebackground="black", fg="lemon chiffon", command=HelpMain, width=4, height=1)
    buttonHelp.place(anchor='se', x=480, y=220)

    window.mainloop()
```

Second problem is that I can't take information from a checkerbox. I need to take true/false to activate/deactivate a text field here is a part with a checkerbox itself:

```
height_chk_state = BooleanVar()  
    height_chk_state.set(False)  
    height_chk = tk.Checkbutton(windowVR, border= "5", bg="gray22", selectcolor="gray15", fg="lemon chiffon", text='Height', var=height_chk_state)  
    height_chk.grid(column=0, row=3)
```

And here is the full code of a window with checkerboxes:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Radiobutton  
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tmb
import tkinter.filedialog as tfd
from tkinter.ttk import Checkbutton 

global windowVR

    def HelpVR():
        tmb.showinfo(f"Help",
                     "blah-blah-blah")

    windowVR = tk.Tk()
    windowVR.resizable(False, False)
    windowVR.geometry("400x150")
    windowVR.title(f"test")
    windowVR.configure(bg="gray22", borderwidth=10)
    
    
    width_chk_state = BooleanVar()  
    width_chk_state.set(False)  
    width_chk = tk.Checkbutton(windowVR, border= "5", bg="gray22", fg="lemon chiffon", selectcolor="gray15", text='Width ', var=width_chk_state)  
    width_chk.grid(column=0, row=1)

    height_chk_state = BooleanVar()  
    height_chk_state.set(False)  
    height_chk = tk.Checkbutton(windowVR, border= "5", bg="gray22", selectcolor="gray15", fg="lemon chiffon", text='Height', var=height_chk_state)  
    height_chk.grid(column=0, row=3)

    ratio_chk_state = BooleanVar()  
    ratio_chk_state.set(False)  
    ratio_chk = tk.Checkbutton(windowVR, border= "5", bg="gray22", fg="lemon chiffon", selectcolor="gray15", text='Ratio   ', var=ratio_chk_state)  
    ratio_chk.grid(column=0, row=5)

    
    global width_condition
    global height_condition
    global ratio_condition
    width_condition = "readonly"
    height_condition="readonly"
    ratio_condition="readonly"
    
    while 1>0:
        if width_chk_state is True:
            width_condition="normal"
            print(width_condition)
        else:
            width_condition = "readonly"
            print(width_condition)
            
            
        if height_chk_state is True:
            height_condition="normal"
            print(height_condition)
        else:
            height_condition="readonly"
            print(height_condition)
            
            
        if ratio_chk_state is True:
                ratio_condition="normal"
                print(height_condition)    
        else:
                ratio_condition="readonly"
                print(ratio_condition)
    
    

    Width = tk.Entry(windowVR, width=30, font=(
        "Arial", 10), bg="gray12", fg="lemon chiffon", state=f"{width_condition}")
    Width.grid(column=5, row=1)
   
    Height = tk.Entry(windowVR, width=30, font=(
        "Arial", 10), bg="gray12", fg="lemon chiffon", state=f"{height_condition}")
    Height.grid(column=5, row=3)

    Ratio = tk.Entry(windowVR, width=30, font=(
        "Arial", 10), bg="gray12", fg="lemon chiffon", state=f"{ratio_condition}")
    Ratio.grid(column=5, row=5)

    print(width_condition)
    print(height_condition)
    print(ratio_condition)
    windowVR.mainloop()
```

I know that windows looks ugly at the moment but it's just a beginning of a demo so please be condescending to my code:) In terms of colors I tried almost every fitting parameter in buttons and stuff. I solved a problem with checkerboxes by changing the 'selectcolor' to black but it is not working with other types of objects. I tried to create a while cycle to check checkerboxes' conditions but either it falls to an infinite loop without any possibility to go further through code or I just can't refresh it without any stops.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUFF4.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJP0b.png)

Comment: `height_chk_state is True` (and several similar pieces of code) cannot ever be true - `height_chk_state` is a BooleanVar, which *contains* a boolean value, it is NOT a boolean value itself.  You have to call `.get()` on the Var to retrieve its value.  And you cannot usefully do this in the same function that created the Vars and widgets, as the user can't have changed the state of the widget yet (or even SEEN the widget!).  Only a running `mainloop()` allows the GUI to actually do anything - but your code never reaches that point due to the infinite `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I'm not at the coding station at the moment but I will reply with the results as I try to use these corrections